# I get "Encoding scheme `TU' unknown." error when I use the Turkish Journal of Mathematics. How to solve this?

Tags: errors, journal

I am writing a manuscript using the Turkish Journal of Mathematics which is obtained from http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/index.htm;jsessionid=D15895BC817F9481A9BEA2BAA5C33E04. Here is my working trial:

```
\documentclass{math}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,enumerate,multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{academicons}
\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\yil{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}

\title{Manuscript template: Full title must be in sentence case \\
\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize  The first page should contain the full title in sentence case (e.g., Multiplication modules with Krull dimension)}}

\author[AUTHOR and AUTHOR]{
\textbf{First AUTHOR$^{1}$\thanks{Correspondence: math@tubitak.gov.tr}~\href{https://orcid.org/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}{\orc},
Second AUTHORP$^{1,2}$\href{https://orcid.org/XXXX-XX12-3456-789X}{\orc}}\\
\textcolor{red}{The
full names (last names fully capitalised) and affiliations (in English) of all authors}\\ 
$^{1}$Department, Faculty, University, City, Country\\
$^{2}$Department of Mathematics, Faculty of Science, \.{I}zmir Institute of Technology, 
\.{I}zmir, Turkey\\
\textcolor{red}{(Department, Faculty, University, City,
Country), and the contact e-mail address for the clearly identified}\\
\textcolor{red}{corresponding author.}
\\ [1.8em]

\rec{.201}
\acc{.201}
\finv{..201}
}


\amssayisi{2010 {\itshape AMS Mathematics Subject Classification:} 23584 \textcolor{red}{(Each manuscript should be accompanied by classification numbers from the American
Mathematical Society classification scheme.)}
\newline
\vspace{-15mm}
\begin{center}
         \raisebox{-17ex}[0ex][0ex]{~~ \raisebox{.5ex}[0ex][0ex]{\footnotesize  This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License.}}
            \end{center}} 

\input{math.tex}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{document}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}The abstract should provide clear information about the research and the results obtained, and should not exceed 200 words. The abstract should not contain citations.

\keywords{Please provide key words or phrases to enable retrieval and indexing. Acronyms should be avoided.}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the error that says:

> Encoding scheme `TU' unknown.

The error that I get looks like this:

[image]

Comment: We can not run your example, but you are loading inputenc package which implies using pdftex but TU encoding is just for luatex and xetex, which tex engine are you using? (unrelated but do not use the epsfig package)

Comment: The `academicons` package and the \orc command requires luatex or xelatex. You can not use it with your template.

Comment: Compile using `xelatex`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the ORCID logo, you need to compile the document with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Otherwise, you need to produce the logo as a standalone PDF, say with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{academicons,xcolor}
\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{orcidlogocol}{\aiOrcid}

\end{document}
```

Save the above file as `orcidlogo.tex` and compile it with XeLaTeX. Then you can modify your document as

```
\documentclass{math}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,enumerate,multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{academicons}
%\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue}

\linenumbers

\yil{}
\vol{}
\fpage{}
\lpage{}
\doi{}

\renewcommand{\orc}{\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`A]{orcidlogo}}

\title{Manuscript template: Full title must be in sentence case \\
\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize  The first page should contain the full
  title in sentence case (e.g., Multiplication modules with Krull dimension)}}

\author[AUTHOR and AUTHOR]{
\textbf{First AUTHOR$^{1}$\thanks{Correspondence: math@tubitak.gov.tr}~%
  \href{https://orcid.org/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}{\orc},
Second AUTHORP$^{1,2}$\href{https://orcid.org/XXXX-XX12-3456-789X}{\orc}}\\
\textcolor{red}{The
full names (last names fully capitalised) and affiliations (in English) of all authors}\\
$^{1}$Department, Faculty, University, City, Country\\
$^{2}$Department of Mathematics, Faculty of Science, \.{I}zmir Institute of Technology,
\.{I}zmir, Turkey\\
\textcolor{red}{(Department, Faculty, University, City,
Country), and the contact e-mail address for the clearly identified}\\
\textcolor{red}{corresponding author.}
\\ [1.8em]

\rec{.201}
\acc{.201}
\finv{..201}
}
```

So long as the `orcidlogo.pdf` file is in the same folder as your main document, you'll be OK.

However, I'd just type in the URL and leave the final job to the journal copy editors.

[image]
*Note.* The list of loaded packages is quite long and full of obsolete or deprecated packages; in particular `epsfig`, `latexsym`, `bezier` should be removed. Also `amsfonts` is already loaded by `amssymb`; `amsgen`, `amsopn` and `amsbsy` are not needed because loaded by `amsmath`; `amscd` is useless because you load `xy` that produces much better diagrams. Finally, `theorem` would not be my choice for managing theorem-like environments.

Comment: Does `height=\fontcharht\font`A` automatically scale up to the current font size if, for example, the text to be followed by the logo has been made `\LARGE`? If not, how do that?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your script since you didn't provide math.cls. However, I have a suggestion to solve the problem of encoding in `academicons`. Although I used `luatex` or `xetex`, I got the same encoding error. I solved it by forcing the encoding:

```
\usepackage[TU]{fontenc}
```

That fixed it but I guess that it is a dirty hack. Any complete answer or background information on the encoding of fonts is welcome.